# Cannot get POST from Bootstrap form to Node server

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I am working on setting up a MEN application using the following clean blog bootstrap template
https://startbootstrap.com/theme/clean-blog

I added a new post functionality to it and I can get the form information to send to my email and I get the JSON object back in the browser console, but for some reason it is not sending the data to my route in Node (using express).
I can use postman to send the same data to Node, which then persists to my mongodb document, so I don't believe it to be my Model or route handling.
Checked other posts about this issue but I don't see what I am missing.
Any help would be appreciated.

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/my_database', {useNewUrlParser: true})

const express = require('express');
const app = new express();
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.static('public'));

const ejs = require('ejs');
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

const BlogPost = require('./models/BlogPost');

const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));

app.get('/', (req, res)=>{
    res.render('index');
});

app.get('/about', (req, res)=>{
    res.render('about');
});

app.get('/contact', (req, res)=>{
    res.render('contact');
});

app.get('/post', (req, res)=>{
    res.render('post');
});

app.get('/posts/new', (req, res)=>{
    res.render('create');
});

app.post('/posts/store',(req,res)=>{
    BlogPost.create(req.body, (error,blogpost)=>{res.redirect('/');});
}); 

app.listen(4000, ()=>{
    console.log("Listening on port 4000...");
});
```

HTML form in create.ejs

```html
<form id="contactForm" action="/posts/store" method="post" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" data-sb-form-api-token="API_TOKEN">
    <div class="form-floating">
        <input class="form-control" name="title" id="title" type="text"/>
        <label for="title">Title</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-floating">
        <textarea class="form-control" name="body" id="body" style="height: 12rem"></textarea>
        <label for="body">Body</label>
    </div>
    <br />
    <!-- Submit success message-->
    <!---->
    <!-- This is what your users will see when the form-->
    <!-- has successfully submitted-->
    <div class="d-none" id="submitSuccessMessage">
        <div class="text-center mb-3">
            <div class="fw-bolder">Form submission successful!</div>
            To activate this form, sign up at
            <br />
            <a href="https://startbootstrap.com/solution/contact-forms">https://startbootstrap.com/solution/contact-forms</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Submit error message-->
    <!---->
    <!-- This is what your users will see when there is-->
    <!-- an error submitting the form-->
    <div class="d-none" id="submitErrorMessage"><div class="text-center text-danger mb-3">Error sending message!</div></div>
    <!-- Submit Button-->
    <button class="btn btn-primary text-uppercase disabled" id="submitButton" type="submit">Send</button>
</form>
```

I don't think its reaching the post method in the code, I put a console log statement there and it only logs on the console (the one running nodemon) when I use postman.  Here is the console view from the browser.  ignore the first line.
[image: console after submitting]

Now that you mention it, it looks like sb-forms-latest.js is involved.  This javascript is well beyond me at my current level

```
/*
* Start Bootstrap - SB Forms v0.4.1 (startbootstrap.com)
* Copyright 2013-2021 Start Bootstrap LLC
*/(() => {
   "use strict";
   var t = function(t, e, n, i) {
       return new(n || (n = Promise))((function(s, a) {
           function r(t) {
               try {
                   d(i.next(t))
               } catch (t) {
                   a(t)
               }
           }

           function o(t) {
               try {
                   d(i.throw(t))
               } catch (t) {
                   a(t)
               }
           }

           function d(t) {
               var e;
               t.done ? s(t.value) : (e = t.value, e instanceof n ? e : new n((function(t) {
                   t(e)
               }))).then(r, o)
           }
           d((i = i.apply(t, e || [])).next())
       }))
   };
   const e = (t, e = document.body) => {
           const n = [].slice.call(e.querySelectorAll(t));
           if (0 === n.length) throw new Error(`GET_ELEMENTS: ${e.id} -> ${t}`);
           return n
       },
       n = (t, e = document.body) => {
           const n = e.querySelector(t);
           if (!n) throw new Error(`GET_ELEMENT: ${e.id} -> ${t}`);
           return n
       };
   var i;
   ! function(t) {
       t.required = "required", t.email = "email", t.length = "length", t.checked = "checked"
   }(i || (i = {}));
   class s {
       constructor(t, e, n) {
           this.input = t, this.validations = e, this.onChange = n, this.isPure = !0, this.inputBlurHandler = () => this.inputBlur(), this.inputInputHandler = () => this.inputInput(), this.inputClickHandler = () => this.inputClick(), t.addEventListener("blur", this.inputBlurHandler), t.addEventListener("input", this.inputInputHandler), t.addEventListener("click", this.inputClickHandler)
       }
       inputBlur() {
           this.isPure = !1, this._handleInputAction()
       }
       inputInput() {
           this._handleInputAction()
       }
       inputClick() {
           this._handleInputAction()
       }
       initValidation() {
           this._handleInputAction()
       }
       _handleInputAction() {
           let t = !0;
           if (this.validations.forEach((e => {
                   t = t && r(this.input, e)
               })), a(this.input)) {
               const n = this.input.parentElement.parentElement,
                   i = e("input", n);
               if (t) {
                   if (i.forEach((t => t.dataset.sbCanSubmit = "yes")), this.isPure) return this.onChange(), void(this.isPure = !1);
                   n.firstElementChild.classList.remove("is-invalid")
               } else {
                   if (i.forEach((t => t.dataset.sbCanSubmit = "no")), this.isPure) return this.onChange(), void(this.isPure = !1);
                   n.firstElementChild.classList.add("is-invalid")
               }
           } else if (t) {
               if (this.input.dataset.sbCanSubmit = "yes", this.isPure) return void this.onChange();
               this.input.classList.remove("is-invalid")
           } else {
               if (this.input.dataset.sbCanSubmit = "no", this.isPure) return void this.onChange();
               this.input.classList.add("is-invalid")
           }
           this.onChange()
       }
       reset() {
           if (this.isPure = !0, a(this.input)) {
               const t = this.input.parentElement.parentElement,
                   n = e("input", t);
               t.firstElementChild.classList.remove("is-invalid"), n.forEach((t => {
                   t.dataset.sbCanSubmit = "no", t.checked = !1
               }))
           } else this.input.value = "", this.input.classList.remove("is-invalid"), this.input.dataset.sbCanSubmit = "no"
       }
       tearDown() {
           this.reset(), this.input.removeEventListener("blur", this.inputBlurHandler), this.input.removeEventListener("input", this.inputInputHandler), this.input.removeEventListener("click", this.inputClickHandler)
       }
   }
   const a = t => !!["checkbox", "radio"].find((e => e === t.type)),
       r = (t, i) => {
           let s, r, c = !0;
           if (a(t) && (r = t.parentElement.parentElement), "object" == typeof i) {
               if (c = i.validate(), s = n(`[data-sb-feedback="${t.id}:${i.name}"]`), !s) throw new Error(`VALIDATION_NOT_SETUP_FOR: ${t.id}:${i.name}`)
           } else {
               switch (i) {
                   case "required":
                       a(t) ? c = e("input", r).reduce(((t, e) => t || e.checked), !1) : t.value || (c = !1);
                       break;
                   case "email":
                       c = o(t.value);
                       break;
                   case "length":
                       c = d(t.value);
                       break;
                   case "checked":
                       c = t.checked
               }
               if (a(t)) try {
                   s = n(`[data-sb-feedback="${t.name}:${i}"]`)
               } catch (e) {
                   throw new Error(`VALIDATION_NOT_SETUP_FOR: ${t.name}:${i}`)
               } else try {
                   s = n(`[data-sb-feedback="${t.id}:${i}"]`)
               } catch (e) {
                   throw new Error(`VALIDATION_NOT_SETUP_FOR: ${t.id}:${i}`)
               }
           }
           return c ? s.classList.add("d-none") : s.classList.remove("d-none"), c
       },
       o = t => /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/.test(String(t).toLowerCase()),
       d = t => t.length > 8;
   (t => {
       const e = document.createElement("style");
       e.textContent = ".d-none {\n    display: none;\n}\n.invalid-feedback {\n    display: none;\n}\n.btn.disabled {\n    pointer-events: none;\n    opacity: 0.65;\n}", document.head.append(e)
   })(), window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", (() => {
       e("form[data-sb-form-api-token]").forEach((t => l(t)))
   }));
   const c = {
       initializeForm: (t, e) => l(t, e)
   };
   window.sbForms = c;
   const l = (r, o) => {
           let d = !0;
           const c = [],
               l = () => {
                   w()
               },
               m = n("#submitButton", r),
               f = n("#submitSuccessMessage", r),
               v = n("#submitErrorMessage", r),
               b = r.dataset.sbFormApiToken;
           "API_TOKEN" === b && (d = !1, console.log(h, p));
           const E = o || e("input, textarea, select", r);
           E.forEach((t => {
               const e = t.dataset.sbValidations;
               e ? (t.dataset.sbCanSubmit = "no", c.push(new s(t, (t => {
                   const e = t.split(",").map((t => t.trim()));
                   return e.forEach((t => {
                       if (!(t in i)) throw new Error(`UNRECOGNIZED_VALIDATION_KEY: ${t}`)
                   })), e
               })(e), l))) : t.dataset.sbCanSubmit = "yes"
           }));
           const y = e => {
                   return n = void 0, i = void 0, a = function*() {
                       e.preventDefault(), m.classList.add("d-none");
                       try {
                           console.log(u(E)), d ? yield(n = {
                               token: b,
                               submissionObject: u(E)
                           }, t(void 0, void 0, void 0, (function*() {
                               const e = yield((e, n) => t(void 0, void 0, void 0, (function*() {
                                   const t = JSON.stringify(n),
                                       i = new Headers({
                                           "Content-Type": "application/json"
                                       }),
                                       s = yield fetch(`https://api.startbootstrap.com${e}`, {
                                           method: "POST",
                                           mode: "cors",
                                           cache: "no-cache",
                                           credentials: "same-origin",
                                           headers: i,
                                           redirect: "follow",
                                           referrerPolicy: "no-referrer",
                                           body: t
                                       });
                                   if (!(s.status >= 200 && s.status < 300)) throw new Error(`FETCH_RETURNED_STATUS: ${s.status}`);
                                   return s
                               })))("/api/latest/solution/forms", n);
                               return yield e.json()
                           }))): console.log(h, p), f.classList.remove("d-none"), E.forEach((t => {
                               t.setAttribute("disabled", "")
                           }))
                       } catch (t) {
                           console.error(t), v.classList.remove("d-none")
                       }
                       var n
                   }, new((s = void 0) || (s = Promise))((function(t, e) {
                       function r(t) {
                           try {
                               d(a.next(t))
                           } catch (t) {
                               e(t)
                           }
                       }

                       function o(t) {
                           try {
                               d(a.throw(t))
                           } catch (t) {
                               e(t)
                           }
                       }

                       function d(e) {
                           var n;
                           e.done ? t(e.value) : (n = e.value, n instanceof s ? n : new s((function(t) {
                               t(n)
                           }))).then(r, o)
                       }
                       d((a = a.apply(n, i || [])).next())
                   }));
                   var n, i, s, a
               },
               L = t => y(t);
           m.addEventListener("click", L);
           const w = () => {
               E.reduce(((t, n) => {
                   if (a(n)) {
                       const i = n.parentElement.parentElement,
                           s = e("input", i);
                       return t && s.reduce(((t, e) => t || "yes" === e.dataset.sbCanSubmit), !1)
                   }
                   return "yes" === n.dataset.sbCanSubmit ? t && !0 : t && !1
               }), !0) ? m.classList.remove("disabled") : m.classList.add("disabled")
           };
           return c.forEach((t => t.initValidation())), w(), {
               tearDown: () => {
                   m.removeEventListener("click", L), f.classList.add("d-none"), v.classList.add("d-none"), m.classList.remove("d-none"), m.classList.add("disabled"), E.forEach((t => {
                       t.removeAttribute("disabled")
                   })), c.forEach((t => t.tearDown()))
               }
           }
       },
       u = t => {
           const e = {};
           return t.forEach((t => {
               if ("checkbox" === t.type || "radio" === t.type) return e[t.name] || (e[t.name] = {}), void(e[t.name][t.id] = t.disabled ? "DISABLED" : t.checked.toString());
               e[t.id] = t.value
           })), e
       },
       h = "%c############################# Start Bootstrap Forms #############################\n###                                                                           ###\n###    To enable this form using Start Bootstrap Forms, simply sign up at:    ###\n###                                                                           ###\n###               https://startbootstrap/solution/contact-forms               ###\n###                                                                           ###\n#################################################################################",
       p = "color: white; font-style: italic; background-color: #dd3d31; padding: 2px;"
})();
```

UPDATE

I removed all of the Javascript running in the background and it works like a charm now.  Also does not to appear to have broke the pages like I though it would.

Comment: Have you verified that the request is hitting the `app.post("/posts/store")` route? Try adding `console.log("/posts/store", req.body)` and see what it logs in your terminal

Comment: How is `data-sb-form-api-token` used? Is there JavaScript involved in submitting the form?

Comment: Check out over here whether the POST call is being fired or not by clicking on browser inspect and going to network tab

Comment: If the call is not being fired In that case, there is something wrong with our frontend, meaning on create.js or if the POST call fired that time needs to be inspected at the server end.

Comment: I see that sb-forms-latest.js is involved in the post request, and I am fairly certain the json data is not making it to that node route

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the JavaScript code that intercepts the form submission and makes the request.

Comment: Would that be the sb-forms-latest.js file?

Comment: updated with sb-forms-0.4.1.js 
I had to download it and format it using https://beautifier.io/

Answer (score 0):

Send

--remove class disabled from button

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).